# Trying to build an Application Layout control similar to the Extension Library

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to make a Layout control similar to the Application Layout in the Extension Library. I think that I will need to use the dojo Layout Controls, but I can not find any documentation on how to use the various dojo Layout Controls. Is there a place where there is some reasonable how to documentation for these controls?

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim pointed out, there is a tutorial which deals specifically with dijit layout widgets.  If this is a new project, I'd recommend using the latest version of Dojo and the version of the tutorial to match though: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dijit_layout/

There is [a wide array of tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/), so perhaps you will find others helpful as well.

For further information, see the Reference Guide's pages for each layout widget:

- [BorderContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html)
- [TabContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html)
- [AccordionContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.html)
- [StackContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/StackContainer.html) (what TabContainer and AccordionContainer are based on)
- [ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html) (often used for mixed content within each region/pane of one of the above containers)
- Not technically in `dijit/layout`, but you might also find [Dialog](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Dialog.html) useful